# Cortana search result window is up in the left corner

Tags: windows-10-preview, cortana

When pressing Ctrl+Q, I'm able to ask Cortana questions with my voice; but for some reason the Cortana search window has been moved to the upper left corner; so I cannot see the results. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in win 10 preview, because sometimes for me it doesn't appear at all.
Right-click on the taskbar, disable and again enable "search". 
If that didn't help, change the screen resolution (right click on desktop) and then switch it back to previous resolution. 
And if none of them worked, i think you should reinstall win 10.